# Big O notation easy problem with for loops

Tags: loops, time-complexity, big-o

What is the Big-O complexity of the following code fragment?

```
const int N = 3;

char arr[N][N][3];

for (int i=0; i<N; i++)

        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)

                for(int k=0; k<3; k++)

                {

                        cout<<”Initial Value: “;

                        cin>>arr[ i ][ j ][ k ];

                }
```

My answer is O(N^3) although I'm unsure because of the last for loop. Can someone clarify?

Comment: Presuming N can vary, it should be O(N^2): O(1) + N \* N \* (3 \* O(1)) = O(1 + 3N^2) = O(N^2)

Answer (score -1):

Big-O complexity of the above code is O(N^3). Even your last loop, has the same value as N i.e. 3.
So yes you're right.